# Prove that $ \int_{|z|=1} \dfrac{1}{\sin^2 z} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to prove that
$$ \int_{|z|=1} \dfrac{1}{\sin^2 z} dz= 0 $$

I tried to solve it by using Euler's formula for $\sin z$, but i something that is too complicated for me. I know that it can be solved by using residue, but i haven't gone over residue yet.

Is there any other way to show it, without using residues?

Comment: Can you find an antiderivative?

Comment: @mrf I didn't think about that. Since $ \dfrac{1}{\sin^2 z} $ got singularities on the unit circle my initial thinking was that it shouldn't be possible to find an antiderivative. I guess my thinking is wrong?

Comment: There are no singularities on the circle. (There is one at $z=0$ but that by itself is not a problem — compare to if the integrand had been $1/z$.)

Comment: @mrf i think i understand now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Let $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ and $\eta(t)=e^{i(t+\pi)}$ ($t\in[0,\pi]$). Then your integral is equal to$$\int_\gamma\frac1{\sin^2z}\,\mathrm dz+\int_\eta\frac1{\sin^2z}\,\mathrm dz.\tag1$$But$$\int_\gamma\frac1{\sin^2z}\,\mathrm dz=\int_0^\pi\frac{ie^{it}}{\sin^2\left(e^{it}\right)}\,\mathrm dt,$$whereas\begin{align}\int_\eta\frac1{\sin^2z}\,\mathrm dz&=\int_0^\pi\frac{ie^{i(t+\pi)}}{\sin^2\left(e^{i(t+\pi)}\right)}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^\pi\frac{-ie^{it}}{\sin^2\left(-e^{it}\right)}\,\mathrm dt\\&=-\int_0^\pi\frac{ie^{it}}{\sin^2\left(e^{it}\right)}\,\mathrm dt\\&=-\int_\gamma\frac1{\sin^2z}\,\mathrm dz\end{align}and therefore $(1)$ is equal to $0$.

Of course, the same argument applies to any even function.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $$\frac{1}{\sin^2 z} = \frac{f(z)}{z^2},$$ where $f(z) := \frac{z^2}{\sin^2 z}$ is a holomorphic function inside of the unit circle.
Cauchy's differentiation formula (which immediatly follows from Cauchy's formula) yields $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{\sin^2 z}\,\mathrm dz = \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z^2} = 2\pi i f'(0) = 0.$$
The derivative does not have to be computed explicitly, note that $f$ has a minumum at $0$.